# Suggested Edit counts on toolbar

Tags: support, suggested-edits, top-bar

Why do I sometimes see a count (usually 5-7) of suggested edits on my SO toolbar and sometimes nothing shows?

Comment: Because sometimes there are no new suggested edits?

Comment: Ah indeed, when there's less than... 5? 6?  There is no notification

Comment: It's 5 @Pëkka... including your own suggestions.

Comment: OK. I thought there were always huge amounts of things to be reviewed.  Must be some other queue I was thinking of.

Comment: The number is configurable per site. The threshold is just *1* for Meta. The suggested edit queue on Stack Overflow goes **very** fast though.

Comment: The question explicitly says SO @Martijn, otherwise yes.

Comment: @ChrisGerken there are typically not many suggested edits in the queue, it would be scary if the close vote queue was on the top-bar.

Comment: @bluefeet Maybe the close-vote review queue size should be displayed, then?  Might get more reviews.

Comment: @ChrisGerken There are plenty of people reviewing the close vote queue, there are just a ton of items to review (100k+) and it grows daily.

Comment: @gnat I wasn't asking that the count be brought back, I just wondered why it was intermittent.

Comment: @Pëkka may be either apply to SO only or doesn't apply to Meta sites.

Answer (score 2):

When you see this, it means that there are some items that might be your choice to review! It is also a notification for you, telling you that 5 - 7 items are available, if you're free, you can go and review them and take action as necessary.

When it doesn't show there, it doesn't mean reviewing process is over, it might mean that you're busy and the system avoided showing you with the items. Why I am saying this, is because I open the page and I get the same 5 - 7 items to be reviewed in Orange color notification, but once I reload the page, its gone! No one can review them in a second but since I was showing minimum attention to that, system ignored me from reviews!

So it is OK to see them and not see them! Try to go and edit and review the post that are active rather than just going in the queue process.